# How to replace specific characters with tab using sed

Tags: sed

I have a file that contain the following text:

```
chr9    116186254   116186404   chr9:116163625-116163775,1  2936    .
chrM    5   155 chrM:16377-16527,1  253 .
```

What I want to do is to remove the non-alphanumeric (i.e. `: , -` ) character with a tab.

I tried this:

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/[:-\,\-]/  /g'
```

But it give me this:

```
chr9    116186254   116186404   chr9  116163625  116163775  1   2936    .
chr     5   155 chr    16377  16527  1  253 .
```

Notice that `chrM` is totally changed to `chr`. What's the right way to do it?

The desired output is

```
chr9    116186254   116186404   chr9  116163625  116163775  1   2936    .
chrM    5   155 chrM    16377  16527  1 253 .
```

Comment: You might want `sed 's/[[:punct:]]/  /g'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to replace any punctuation with a tab char using

```
sed 's/[[:punct:]]/\t/g' test.txt > test.out.txt
```

Or, any chunk of punctuation chars with a single tab:

```
sed -E 's/[[:punct:]]+/\t/g' test.txt > test.out.txt
sed 's/[[:punct:]][[:punct:]]*/\t/g' test.txt > test.out.txt
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/HIcEAm).

In these latter two examples, `-E` enables a POSIX ERE syntax to use an unescaped `+` as a quantifier that matches 1 or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern. The BRE POSIX variant requires `[[:punct:]][[:punct:]]*` where `[[:punct:]]*` matches 0  or more punctuation marks. Note that in GNU `sed`, this BRE POSIX pattern may be written as `[[:punct:]]\+` (where `\+` is the same as `+` in the POSIX ERE pattern, a quantifier).